# "or" match pattern in redis scan

Tags: redis

Is there something like "or" in `SCAN` match patterns in Redis? I need to match a complicated keys like:

> 00,All+cities|123, 00,Paris|234, 00,London|345

Is it possible to match `Paris` **or** `All cities` using `SCAN`?

Something like:

> SCAN 0 match 00,[Paris] **||** [All+cities]*

Thanks.

Comment: No there isn't. You need to create a secondary index,

Comment: Or use redisearch /cc @Not_a_Golfer